# If $f$ is an even function defined on the interval $(-5,5)$ then four real values of $x$ satisfying the equation $f(x)=f(\frac{x+1}{x+2})$ are?

Tags: functions

If $f$ is an even function defined on the interval $(-5,5)$ then four real values of $x$ satisfying the equation $f(x)=f(\frac{x+1}{x+2})$ are?

I thought that $(x+1)/(x+2)=-x$.But I'm getting only two values by solving this.How do I get the other two values?

And if i put $(x+1)/(x+2)=x$ then the answer is not matching.I dont know why.

Comment: Looks like you have it.  Each equation give you 2 solutions... put it together and you have 4.

Comment: What do you mean the answer is not matching?  That case gives $x=\frac 12(-3\pm \sqrt 5)$, no?

Comment: The other solution given in my book is $1/2(3+\sqrt(5))$ and  $1/2(3-\sqrt(5))$

Comment: Well, Wolfram alpha agrees with $-3$.  If that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the possibility $(x+1)/(x+2)=+x$.

Setting $\frac{x+1}{x+2}=-x$ leads to $x+1=-x^2-2x$, i.e., $x^2+3x+1=0$, $x=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{5}}2$. Setting $\frac{x+1}{x+2}=+x$ leads to $x+1=x^2+2x$, i.e., $x^2+x-1=0$, $x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}2$.
All four values are well within $(-5,5)$.

Comment: But that is giving the wrong answer.I dont know why.In my book the other condition they used is $f(x)=f(-x)=f((-x+1)/(-x+2))$ and so $x=(-x+1)/(-x+2)$.I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Well, that would lead to $-x^2+2x=-x+1$, i.e., $x^2-3x+1=0$, $x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: No.See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(-x%2B1)%2F(-x%2B2)%3Dx

Comment: You made a calculation error. $x^2-2x=x-1$ gives $x^2-3x+1=0$

Comment: Nevertheless, $x=\frac{-x+1}{-x+2}$ does not entail $f(x)=f(\frac{x+1}{x+2})$.

Comment: Well i dont know why they solved it using that in my book.BTW the question is from IITJEE 1996.Well i'll overlook it for the time being.